# Dummy variable in Fourier Transform and Integrals in General

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I have a question regarding the use of dummy variables in Fourier Transforms. More specifically, the replacement of a dummy variable of integration inside an integral with another. One of the steps in my textbook required to prove the inverse Fourier transform from the Fourier transform involves a dummy variable such that the following must be true:

$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(k)e^{ikx}dk=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(u)e^{iux}du$$

IF this is true, one can eventually end up reaching the conclusion that:

$$\phi(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$

What I don't fully understand is: how come were allowed to simply switch the $k$ for a $u$? I guess a more general question regarding the specific part that I have a doubt with is if, in general, one can switch variables in any integral such that the following is always true:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(k)dk=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)du$$

For any $k$ and $u$. Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as a u-substitution, so $k=u \text{ and } dk = du$. But this is solely notation - you're looking at the inverse Fourier transform which is $\phi(x)$, which does not depend at all on the dummy variable.

You can't just swap any $k$ for any $u = p(k)$ without also determining the new differential $du = p'(k) dk$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always write $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(k)\,dk=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)\,du$. Heck, you can even write $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\ddot{\smile})\,d\ddot{\smile}$, or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(@)\,d@$ or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\sharp)\,d\sharp$. Why? That's just notation.

In general, to talk about integration you need only 2 pieces of information:

- First you need the (nice-enough) function $f$ you're interested in. For now let us focus on functions $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$. Here, let me emphasize that functions are rules: $f$ assigns to each $n$-tuple in $\Bbb{R}^n$ a certain real number. So, these functions are denoted by a single letter $f$. They do not come attached with a variable name like "$f(x)$" or "$f(k)$" or "$f(p)$" or whatnot.
- Next you need the domain of integration, i.e a nice set $E\subset\Bbb{R}^n$.

With these two pieces of information, we can just write the integral as $\int_Ef$; this is the (say RIemann) integral of the function $f$ over the set $E$. That's it. There's no need to bring in auxillary letters $x,u,v,k,t,\xi,\eta,\kappa$ or whatever (sure in hands-on calculations we may like some choices of letters over others; but that's a choice of preference, not dictated by logical necessity. For more about this, you may want to read [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3498849/568204)). This should make sense, because math does not care what your favorite letters are; what is important are the concepts (in this case, integrals, functions and domains of integration).

In single variable calculus, we may be interested in the set $E=[a,b]$ with $a\leq b$, in which case we adopt the notation $\int_a^bf$ in place of $\int_{[a,b]}f$. Similarly, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$ means $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f$.

---

Some side remarks: if you're considering Lebesgue integration, then in $\Bbb{R}^n$ one typically considers the Lebesgue measure, which is typically denoted as $\lambda_n$, or $m_n$, in which case the integrals are written $\int_Ef\,d\lambda_n$ (or $\int_Ef\,dm_n$). Again, there's no necessity for arbitrary letters like $x,u,v,t,k,p...$ (though in practice one sees the notation $\int_Ef(x)\,d\lambda_n(x)$ or simply $\int_Ef(x)\,d^nx$; but again this is for convenience, not out of logical necessity).